# Where to put pthread flags in a MakeFile?

Tags: makefile

I am trying to compile a program using a MakeFile.  However, I cannot seem to figure out where to stick the flag to get it to recognize pthreads, or even what exactly that flag is.
I've done a little searching on this subject, but I feel the results I've found are not clear on how to solve the problem, so I bring the question to a forum post.

Anyway, here's the contents of my file.  I've marked the spots I think the flag could go.

```
#CC = cc
CFLAGS=-Wall (flag here?)
OUTFILE=app

# Debug flags
DFLAGS=-g -DDEBUG

# Release flags
RFLAGS=

# Targets to build
SOURCES=PosixSavings.c

.PHONY: all
all: CFLAGS+=$(RFLAGS)
all: link

.PHONY: all-debug
all-debug: CFLAGS+=$(DFLAGS)
all-debug: link

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    $(RM) $(SRCcIR)/*~
    $(RM) $(INCDIR)/*~
    $(RM) *~
    $(RM) *.o
    $(RM) $(OUTFILE)

link:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(SOURCES) -o $(OUTFILE) (flag here?)
```

If the solution exists here already and I've missed it, feel free to point me to it.
Thank you very much.

Comment: You don't say what exact flags you're trying to add, and you don't say what you've tried, and you don't say how what you tried didn't work.  Plus this is a bizarre makefile; there's hardly any point in having a makefile here; you could get the same behavior with a simple shell script.

Comment: I see.  I apologize.  The flag I need is either -pthread or -lpthread. I have tried placing those flags at the marked locations as well as other places in the code and I have had no results.   Also, I agree that it would be simpler to do this manually, but this is for a school assignment and the professor wants a MakeFile.

Comment: What do you mean by "no results"?  Does the build fail?  Does your program fail?  Why do you think there's a problem?  Also you don't say what compiler you're using; the flag may be different for different compilers.  However, for GCC the correct flag is `-pthread` and it can come anywhere on the command line.

Comment: Again, I apologize for the oversight.  The build does in fact fail because the compiler tells me that all the pthread functions are undefined.  And yes, I am using GCC.

Comment: I have tried adding -pthread to the make file and the build continues to fail., saying that the function references are undefined.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what to tell you, because it works fine for me:

```
$ cat /tmp/pt.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void* start(void* arg) { return arg; }

int main() { pthread_t pt; pthread_create(&pt, NULL, start, NULL); return 0; }
```

Now if I run *without* `-pthread` I get:

```
$ cc -Wall -g -DDEBUG /tmp/pt.c -o /tmp/pt
/tmp/ccFyRHKv.o: In function `main':
/tmp/pt.c:6: undefined reference to `pthread_create'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

If I add `-pthread` (and it doesn't matter where I put it):

```
$ cc -Wall -pthread -g -DDEBUG /tmp/pt.c -o /tmp/pt
```

No errors or warnings are printed.

So, you need to edit your question and show the compile line that make prints out, and the exact errors that are generated (please cut and paste them into your question then add spaces so they appear as code blocks).  Then maybe we can figure out what's going on.