# How can I modify my makefile to allow me to include<pthread.h>?

Tags: c, linux, makefile, pthreads

I am modifying an example btstack program in C. Btstack includes a makefile for porting to the raspberry pi. I need to have a timer running in the background while other things are running so I am attempting to tinker with pthreads. I've installed the library with "sudo apt-get ...." and included it in my .c file. When I attempt to compile, I get the following error (although unlike other errors it is in grey text and not red):

```
/usr/bin/ld: le_data_channel_server.o: undefined reference to symbol 'pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.4'
/usr/bin/ld: //lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [../../example/Makefile.inc:502: le_data_channel_server] Error 1
```

Here are the contents of the makefile as is:

```
# Makefile for Raspberry Pi
BTSTACK_ROOT ?= ../..

CORE += \
    btstack_chipset_bcm.c \
    btstack_chipset_bcm_download_firmware.c \
    btstack_control_raspi.c \
    btstack_link_key_db_tlv.c \
    btstack_run_loop_posix.c \
    btstack_tlv_posix.c \
    btstack_uart_posix.c \
    btstack_slip.c \
    hci_dump_posix_fs.c \
    hci_transport_h4.c \
    hci_transport_h5.c \
    le_device_db_tlv.c \
    main.c \
    wav_util.c                  \
    btstack_stdin_posix.c \
    raspi_get_model.c \
    rijndael.c

# examples
include ${BTSTACK_ROOT}/example/Makefile.inc

# use (cross)compiler for Raspi
CC = arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc

CFLAGS  += -g -Wall -Werror \
    -I$(BTSTACK_ROOT)/platform/embedded \
    -I$(BTSTACK_ROOT)/platform/posix \
    -I$(BTSTACK_ROOT)/chipset/bcm \
    -I${BTSTACK_ROOT}/3rd-party/tinydir \
    -I${BTSTACK_ROOT}/3rd-party/rijndael



# add 'real time' lib for clock_gettime
LDFLAGS += -lrt

VPATH += ${BTSTACK_ROOT}/3rd-party/rijndael
VPATH += ${BTSTACK_ROOT}/platform/posix
VPATH += ${BTSTACK_ROOT}/platform/embedded

VPATH += ${BTSTACK_ROOT}/chipset/bcm    

EXAMPLES = ${EXAMPLES_GENERAL} ${EXAMPLES_CLASSIC_ONLY} ${EXAMPLES_LE_ONLY} ${EXAMPLES_DUAL_MODE}
EXAMPLES += pan_lwip_http_server

# use pkg-config for portaudio
# CFLAGS  += $(shell pkg-config portaudio-2.0 --cflags) -DHAVE_PORTAUDIO
# LDFLAGS += $(shell pkg-config portaudio-2.0 --libs)
# hard coded flags for portaudio in /usr/local/lib
# CFLAGS  += -I/usr/local/include -DHAVE_PORTAUDIO
# LDFLAGS += -L/sw/lib -lportaudio -Wl,-framework,CoreAudio -Wl,-framework,AudioToolbox -Wl,-framework,AudioUnit -Wl,-framework,Carbon

all: ${EXAMPLES}
```

Basically, what should I modify/add in the makefile that would allow me to compile the program in the rpi command line with a "make" command?

Edit: MFisherKDX's solution worked. I added
`LDFLAGS += -lpthread` to the makefile.

Comment: Add `-lpthread` to the link-time options (placed after the object files).  The problem is not the header; the problem is that you omitted the library.  You may be able to use a shortcut like `-thread` (check spelling) to get the right options added more simply.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/29320698/1216776

Comment: I'm guessing you already are including pthread.h properly from your .c file.  If not, you'd get a compile error that the pthread.h file isn't found.  add -lpthread to your LDFLAGS

Comment: Jonathan, thanks for the comment. I'm not sure what you mean by the "-thread" shortcut. I should add that I tried `gcc program_name.c -lpthread` but received a "No such file or directory" error for the btstack headers.

Comment: Your original error message came from `ld` and was about a missing symbol. Now you're having problems creating a `.o` file.  You need to sort out the problems sequentially.  Do you have the pthread development headers and libraries installed?  Where are they installed?  Will the compiler look for the header where it is installed?  If not, you need to guide the compiler where to look for the headers, and probably where to look for the libraries too.  It may be sufficient to use `gcc -pthread …` to find and use the pthread headers and libraries.

Comment: In your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68684811/how-h#comment121383687_68684811), you are missing instructions for where to find the BTStack headers — there's a list of 5 directories in the `CFLAGS +=` macro.

Comment: For GCC, the correct approach is to add the `-pthread` option to both the C compiler flags and the linker flags.  That will take care of linking the correct library, but *it may also have other effects*.  Although adding `-lpthread` to the list of link libraries may resolve your link error, it is, in principle, neither necessary nor sufficient for building a working pthreads program with GCC.